# How to fix 302 Found CURL?

Tags: php, xml, curl, http-status-code-302

I am trying to send XML data through CURL with HTTP POST in PHP script. I am getting following message on execution.

**Found**
The document has moved [here](http://www.example.com/1.1/home/).

And here is my code.

```
<?php
$url = "https://usm.channelonline.com/REQUEST";

$post_string = '<export_documents_request schemaVersion="4.0">
  <options>
    <onlyUnexported>false</onlyUnexported>
    <eventInRange>
      <eventType>modified</eventType>
      <after>2005-01-01T10:00:00Z</after>
    </eventInRange>
  </options>
</export_documents_request>';


$header  = "POST HTTP/1.1 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
$header .= $post_string;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

if(curl_errno($ch))
    print curl_error($ch);
else
    echo $data;
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

And here is screen view on execution.

[image]

I am good in PHP but just familiar with CURL. Can you help me out how to fix this issue?

Comment: Using `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` it should follow the redirect. I suspect the server responds with `200 OK` and prints the `Found` message, rather than responding with a `302` or `301` code.

Comment: what headers does this response sends to you?

Comment: How did you fix the problem? I am having the same problem...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either, like MrCode pointed out, the server doesn't really respond with 301/302 or your PHP is running in safe mode, which doesn't allow for using `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`.

Comment: if PHP would running in safe mode it would generate Fatal error like `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set`